# if we can use Email Services instead of Email-to-Case, but still use the Ref ID/Thread ID

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, email2case, apexrest

**Email Services addresses do not show up when selecting the FROM drop-down when sending an email from a case record.**

Therefore, it does not allow us to use the Thread ID or Ref ID, which means our customers' replies are not showing up as inbound emails of the original case record.

Is it possible to use Email Services that reference custom Apex class and still use the Ref ID or Thread ID so that our customers' email replies show up as inbound emails in the original case? Does this require a developer to add code in the Apex class to include the Ref ID or Thread ID?  Or, can we create an organization-wide email address to handle this? Does organization-wide email addresses show up in the FROM drop-down menu when sending an email from a case?

**

Overall, just want to know if we can use Email Services instead of Email-to-Case, but still use the Ref ID/Thread ID so that customers' emails display as inbound emails in the original case.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. It seems like you are trying to use an Email Service to handle the emails instead of Email-to-Case because you can't send from an Email-to-Case email address?

Answer (score 2):

If you add your email to case email address to organization-wide email addresses and give permissions to the correct profiles, your agents should be able to send emails from a case that look like they come from the email to case email address. They will also include the Ref Id if sent from the case and it is configured to be added in the Case settings.

Comment: Thanks for the update Also.will test the same.....Is it possible to use the Case's Ref ID or Thread ID when using Email Services that point to an Apex Class? Is there any sample code

Comment: No, you can't query for thread ID. See this post to understand how the thread ID is created: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk. You could theoretically get enough of the case ID out of it to find the correct case.

Comment: You can't query the thread ID however you could create a custom ref or use case- id as a unique reference for related emails

Comment: are you saying that we can create a new organization-wide email address and have that address forward to all the email service addresses? Or, do we have to add each of our many email service addresses (we have 26 total) to the organization-wide email address?
It sounds like the key thing is that organization-wide email addresses can be used as the FROM drop-down when a support agent sends an email from within a case and that Ref ID/Thread ID works with organization-wide email addresses. @Daniel

Comment: You have to add each each email address to the org-wide emails. This would let your agent pick their from address. And yes, the thread ID would be appended.

Comment: I added abc@abc.com to our org-wide email addresses.I go to a case and go to the Emails related list and click Send Email. On the FROM drop-down menu, I can now see the org-wide email address abc@abc.com. I select it.I sent a test email to some personal test email address (my yahoo address). I go to my Yahoo inbox and I can see that test email come in from abc@abc.com. I see that it includes a Ref ID on the subject and body. I reply back from my personal yahoo address.

Comment: When I check Salesforce, I expect the case to show this incoming email address in the Emails related list, but instead it shows up as a new case. So, it didn't work even though it contains the Ref ID.Please let me know what I'm missing. @DanielHoechst

Comment: When you look at the email that was received in Salesforce, it has the thread ID on it?